# Cannot upload back up photos Library to iCloud

Tags: icloud, photos, data-synchronization

After I changed iPhones, my Photos library became corrupted: albums disappeared, the order of albums was all over the place, etc. Given this, I decided to start from scratch.

I deleted all photos and albums directly on the iCloud website and purged all deleted items. In short, the Photos library was wiped clean.

I took the Photos library from my Time Machine back up from a couple of days prior to this and made it the new system library and turned on iCloud.

The issue is that the Photos library in the cloud takes priority and it proceeds to erase all the photos on the new system library on my MacBook. It is basically trying to match what is in the cloud (basically nothing) by deleting everything on my computer’s Photos library.

How can I force the system to make the new system library take priority and upload the photos from my Macbook to the cloud?

Comment: Did you disable iCloud Photo Library before restoring the backup?

Comment: When you restore the photo library with Time Machine, ensure it's not marked as the System Library. If you already have a library in ~/Pictures, don't replace it. Then after you've restored it as a non-syncing library, mark it as the system library and it should sync up.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. 

This is what I did, I took the back up photos library from the Time Machine and copied it on an external drive (to ensure I had a safe copy). 

I then deleted the existing photos library (located in /Pictures) by dragging the file to the trash/bin and copied the back up library from the external deive to /Pictures, opened it and made it the system library.